# Format date field

Tags: perl, datetime

I want to reformat my data to populate a database.

This is a sample of a 9GB 60 column CSV file that I want to reformat.

```
DATE,TIME,CRSPTM1,CRSPME1,CRSPLC1,CRSPMI1,CRSPSC1,CRSPMC1,CRSPSX1,CRSPTMT
20140303,9:30:00,1407.02,1394.69,1399.76,1426.59,1444.68,1498.23,1460.91,1495.53
20140303,9:30:01,1403.34,1391.57,1396.47,1422.47,1439.05,1488.27,1454.67,1491.61
20140303,9:30:02,1402.23,1390.97,1395.69,1420.78,1435.81,1486.59,1451.49,1490.43
20140303,9:30:03,1402.23,1391.01,1395.72,1420.72,1435.65,1486.62,1451.37,1490.43
20140303,9:30:04,1402.31,1391.15,1395.83,1420.70,1435.57,1486.63,1451.28,1490.52
20140303,9:30:05,1402.13,1390.95,1395.64,1420.58,1435.42,1486.56,1451.10,1490.33
20140303,9:30:06,1402.00,1390.84,1395.50,1420.29,1435.32,1486.58,1450.99,1490.18
20140303,9:30:07,1401.96,1390.83,1395.47,1420.15,1435.24,1486.47,1450.91,1490.14
20140303,9:30:08,1401.75,1390.55,1395.24,1420.17,1435.11,1486.27,1450.76,1489.92
```

The first two fields are, for example, `20140303,9:30:00` and I need to change this into MySQL DateTime format

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.

I see on several posts that Perl has a `DateTime` module and would like to use that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the sample as text instead of an image showing that text. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/874188)

Comment: Your problem can be solved simply by inserting dashes in a couple of places and replacing a comma with a space. There are already hundreds, if not thousands, of questions here about trivial regex substitutions on date strings. Maybe delete this question and ask a new one once you have some code and need help with it (but please understand that *repeatedly* deleting your own questions is problematic for other reasons).

Comment: @tripleee Yes I get your point.  Could you help me understand my thought process - I know Awk will help in processing large files and after reading your comment, I can think of using grep, that makes sense.  I am primarily an R programmer and would like to understand that Perl could have been used here in the same capacity as Awk or not.  I'll update my question with Grep answer/attempt.  Thanks

Comment: What's gg? This is easy to do in any regex tool; if you want to learn Perl, by all means go with that. The Awk-like field splitting with `-aF,`  might be helpful.

Comment: That script seems largely unrelated. This is literally a one-liner in Perl or Awk. `grep` is not a tool which offers substitution capabilities.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks ▬ so I gather: Perl one-liner will do my 9GB file like Awk one-liner; no need to compile a script and process one line at a time with `open(FILE..` and then `while(<FILE>) {..` rather a one liner is good enough here.

Comment: Absolutely. If you read and write a line at a time, memory usage will be insignificant. Just search for another regex question with similar requirements, it doesn't matter much in which language (but keep in mind that `grep`, `sed`, Awk, and Perl all have distinct regex dialects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for the `DateTime` module here. This is simple text reformatting

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d),/$1-$2-$3 /' myfile.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for answer & reformat.  I have the answer and better equipped now to delve into a bit of perl everyday.  I am trying to deduce the usage of your code from [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) and [regex](http://jkorpela.fi/perl/regexp.html) docs.  But in the meanwhile another quick newbie question: when working with formatting big files I should, I think, use `>` operand to save the stdout from bash prompt.  Is there other another quick tip here for me on how to do this efficiently, maybe a way to not copy the file to a new file , or cut the machine overhead somehow.

Comment: @B.L.Sher: *"cut the machine overhead somehow"* Is there a problem with the solution as it stands?

Comment: I am gonna delete that comment because my main concern, time to process this command, was a non-concern, it took only ~5 minutes to carry out this perl command.  The second part about not making a copy is not a real concern, make a copy and delete it.  But for my understanding I'd like to know this trivial distinction that ▬ if you had to do this you'd make a copy, i.e. you are not going into the `csv` file and changing one row at a time. That is what I gather from you answer to an earlier comment.

Comment: @B.L.Sher: You can't easily edit a file *in-place* unless the new line lengths are identical to the old ones. If they are different lengths then the data must be moved about anyway, and there's no gain over moving them to a different file.

Answer (score -1):

As I see, you actually need to change the first 8 chars of each line (but the
first). You need to insert `-` chars after year section (4 chars) and month
section (another 2 chars).

Assuming that your input file is *inp.txt* you can use the following one-liner script:

```
perl –lne "print s/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1-$2-$3/r" inp.txt
```

To avoid creation of any extra variables, I used the substitution with
*non-destructive* (*-r*) option, so the result of `s/.../.../` instruction
is the substitution result (not the number of substitutions).

The first line (column names) will not be changed, because it does not match
the regex used.

If you want to store the result in another file, add `>out_file.txt` to the above command.

If something is still unclear, you probably shoud read a little about:

- *perl* options (at least those used here),
- *perl* one-liners,
- regular expressions.

Comment: You'll also want to replace the first comma with a space if I read the requirements correctly.